# Color of underlying view seen above overlapping view android

Tags: android, achartengine

I have a bar graph using aChartEngine library for android. Everything is fine except that the grid lines are visible inside the bar item. I want the grid lines but don't want it inside the blue bar items as seen in the image below:

There doesn't seem to be any functionality in aChartEngine for that. What exactly is the problem? I have also set opacity and alphas. But they aren't working either.

[image]

Comment: It seems like the color of the bars has a level of transparency.

Comment: I have put the alpha to full visibility, but still the transparent background is being shown